# How can I populate ComboBox edit field with ValueMember but show DisplayMember in the list?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, validation, combobox

I have an editable ComboBox with a validation on the `Text` property to make sure manually entered info is valid.

**EDIT:** All I want to do is populate the `.Text` property with the `ValueMember` of a selection rather than the `DisplayMember`

I also have the `.Items` populated with valid entries having the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` set.

My `DisplayMember` is a caption along with the data, and the `ValueMember` is the data itself.

So `Items` might be:

```
(DisplayMember, ValueMember)
"Foo - 1ab2"  , "1ab2"
"Bar - 3cd4"  , "3cd4"
```

I had a validation on the text which can also validate manual user input like "5ef6"

The problem I'm having is that if the user selects an item from the combobox it populates the text field with the `DisplayMember` property (ex: "Foo - 1ab2") which will fail validation.

I have tried to manually set the `.Text` property with the `SelectedValue` or the `SelectedItem.Value` on each of the three relevant combobox events to no avail.

I would like that the `.Text` of the ComboBox get populated with the `.ValueMember` of the item when selected rather than the `.DisplayMember`

**EDIT:** I cannot validate by trying to extrapolate the value from the caption. I send the `Text` off to a service to be validated.

```
void FillMyCombo
{
    KeyValuePair<string, string> listValue1 = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Foo - 1ab2"  , "1ab2")
    KeyValuePair<string, string> listValue2 = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Bar - 3cd4"  , "3cd4")
    myCombo.Items.Add(listValue1);
    myCombo.Items.Add(listValue2);

    myCombo.DisplayMember = "Key";
    myCombo.ValueMember = "Value";
}

...

void myCombo_TextUpdated
{
    if(!myValidationService.Validate(myCombo.Text))
    {
        do error stuff
    }
}
```

The user can manually enter something like "5ef6" which will pass validation.
But when they select an item from the list, rather than manually entering it, the `.Text` property gets filled with the *caption* and not the *value* ... so it will contain "Foo - 1ab2" and that will fail validation.

**EDIT:** In response to an answer posted: I cannot change the validation method to "infer" the value from the caption. I have no control over that service. All I'm after is the **displayed value**

**EDIT:** Say a user selects "Foo - 1ab2" from the dropdown list, I want the text in the box to say "1ab2"

**EDIT:** I have also tried to set the `.Text` property in code but I can't seem to make it work in any of the ComboBox events. If anybody can answer how to programmaticly set the `.Text` property (and make it commit!) on a selection event they will also answer this question.

Comment: You're putting the _caption_ up for selection and editing. As there seems to be a relation you could fix the validation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I cannot validate the caption, I can only validate the value. But the ComboBox populates the `Text` property with the caption, not the value. That is the problem I have.

Comment: Your setup does not allow for creating or editing the value part. Why validate at all?

Comment: @HenkHolterman This is an editable combobox. The user can manually enter their own values, in addition to the items in the list. This is standard combobox behavior `.DropDownStyle = DropDown` and thus the manual entry must be validated.

Comment: Better show some code concerning the Value and Display types and the binding. I'm lost.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I added some code to hopefully show you what I'm talking about. The user can enter text in the control *or* select a pre-entered value from the list.

Comment: Looks like you set yourself an inconsistent target. "How to validate the city when the user types the street"

Comment: @Henk Well why not validate manually entered items against a backend if the client does not have a complete list in items?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Not quite. I always want to validate the value, which is what the user enters, and is what the `.ValueMember` contains. The `.DisplayMember` is a caption include *metadata* about the `.ValueMember`, which seems the purpose of the caption anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/11/19/c-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-displaying-different-values-in-drop-down-list/ -- they change `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` on the fly upon dropdown opening/closing.

Example is for `DatagridViewComboBox`. A ComboBox has those events, too, no?

Give it a try and downvote if it does not help :)=

** Update **

Another good-looking solution might be [ArgumentException when adding ComboBox column to DataGridView with same DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503649/problem-when-adding-combobox-to-datagridview), there look at the not-accepted answer.

Comment: +1 Ah ha! From skimming the article this just might work. I'll come back and accept later when I get a chance to test the code in my app.

Comment: Dunno for sure if this is yet another good suggestion, but -- see update.

Comment: Your link resolved my problem! What I did was set `.DisplayMember` to different properties in the `DropDown` and `DropDownClosed` events

Comment: How crazy. Let's hope this is not implementation-specific. Then it will cease to function properly sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Simply validate the `.SelectedText` property of the `ComboBox` instance. `.Text` will always contain what the user sees, i.e. the display property's value:

```
void myCombo_TextUpdated
{
    if(!myValidationService.Validate(myCombo.SelectedText))
    {
        do error stuff
    }
}
```

`SelectedText` gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a `ComboBox`, I think even if SelectedIndex=-1/SelectedValue=Null.

Comment: I cannot validate the the `.SelectedValue`. I do not control the validation service. Furthermore, when the user manually enters text the `.SelectedValue` will be `null`

Comment: you say you dont control teh validation service, but do you have control over what gets SENT to the service for validation?

Comment: @Stuart yes I do, and I could simply check if `.SelectedValue` is `null` before deciding to send `.Text` or `.SelectedValue` but that doesn't resolve the problem of what displays....

Comment: After confusing the whole thing with a DataGridView, I woke up :) and believe to have a valid answer -- see updated answer of mine.

Comment: @TheBlastOne No dice, even if I can make the validation work, the problem is that I need to **display** the value in the field, not the caption. I edited question to try and clarify!